# Which iOS and Lion third-party apps support "Documents in the Cloud"?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud

Which apps in iOS and Lion support the "Documents in the Cloud" feature from iCloud? I know that Apple's own iWork apps support this. But other than Apple's own apps, which third-party apps implement this?

It would be helpful to know the name of the app as well as how it uses "Documents in the Cloud". For instance:

- Pages, it allows you to save your documents
- Instacast, keep last listened to position in podcasts in sync.

One app per answer, please, to keep the results focused. Please check before you answer, duplicate answers will be deleted.

Comment: Converted to Wiki

Comment: Is no-one answering this for any reason?  I know there are basically no iCloud apps for Mac yet (there is 1 lsiting when you search in MAS), but there are plenty for iOS I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- I use **SigleText** ([website](http://www.worqbench.com/singletext/) | [App Store link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/singletext/id471061293?mt=8&uo=4) | [MAS link](http://itunes.apple.com/it/app/singletext/id471095690?mt=12)) to share notes between my iPhone and my Mac; it uses iCloud storage.
- As far as I know, **iTunes Movie Trailer** app and **Doodle Jump** app use iCloud storage to sync your settings between iOS devices.
- Worth to mention: [**Instacast**](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=instacast&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvemedio.com%2Fproducts%2Finstacast&ei=izahTuOuOsWmhAf2-aHMBA&usg=AFQjCNGCANXSa_OfLo3D_mLU1zwtze08WQ&sig2=gLUI4Kd1W_p31n8n8TgrQQ). The last version sync your podcasts (played status, favorites, resume playing location) thanks to iCloud. The developer said is going to launch an iPad version, so this feature should be very handy in the future.